# rvalue Reference not matching

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, assert, rvalue-reference

I have this exercise in which we try various combinations of rvalue and lvalue references using a template class, I am getting two assertion errors; if someone could guide.

```
#include <assert.h>

typedef int& IntLRef;
typedef IntLRef& IntLLRef;
typedef IntLRef&& IntLRRef;

typedef int&& IntRRef;
typedef IntRRef& IntRLRef;
typedef IntRRef&& IntRRRef;

template<typename T, typename U>
struct IsSameType
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct IsSameType <T, T>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
static_assert(IsSameType<IntLRef, IntLLRef>::value, "LRef DIF LLRef"); static_assert(IsSameType<IntLRef, IntLRRef>::value, "LRef DIF LRRef"); static_assert(IsSameType<IntLLRef, IntLRRef>::value, "LLRef DIF LRRef");

static_assert(IsSameType<IntRRef, IntRLRef>::value, "RRef DIF RLRef"); static_assert(IsSameType<IntRRef, IntRRRef>::value, "RRef DIF RRRef"); static_assert(IsSameType<IntRLRef, IntRRRef>::value, "RLRef DIF RRRef");

int main();
```

I am getting assertion error :

```
rvalue_ex3.cpp:34:48: error: static assertion failed: RRef DIF RLRef
   34 |   static_assert(IsSameType<IntRRef, IntRLRef>::value, "RRef DIF RLRef");
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
rvalue_ex3.cpp:36:49: error: static assertion failed: RLRef DIF RRRef
   36 |   static_assert(IsSameType<IntRLRef, IntRRRef>::value, "RLRef DIF RRRef");
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
akm009@a
```

I need to make modfications to assert it as true and understand why it is failing

Comment: its not clear what you are asking or what you want to achieve. You can assert `! IsSameType<...` , but I suppose thats not what you want, what do you want?

Comment: Btw: Your `IsSameType` functionality is already available via the standard library, including a variable template: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same E.g. `IsSameType<IntLRef, IntLLRef>::value` could be replaced with `std::is_same_v<IntLRef, IntLLRef>` Also you should include `cassert` instead of `assert.h` when using C++ and you do not need this include for `static_assert` to be available in C++...

Comment: Note: the special properties of the `main` function make a declaration of the `main` function pointless in 99.99% of all cases. It must not be called anywhere in your program, so knowing the exact signature is usually of no benefit to you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference):

> It is permitted to form references to references through type
> manipulations in templates or typedefs, in which case the reference
> collapsing rules apply: *rvalue reference to rvalue reference collapses
> to rvalue reference, all other combinations form lvalue reference*

(emphasis added)

Which means that `IntRRef` which is `int&&` is not the same as `IntRLRef` because the latter is defined as `IntRRef&` which is an lvalue reference to an rvalue reference and thus collapses to an **lvalue** reference: `int&`.